# sequelize parseint INTEGER

Tags: sequelize.js

When getting values from a form(req.body) do I have to run parseInt or can I tell sequelize to set it to 0 if the value is a empty string?

Using:

```
req.body.price_low_day = parseInt(req.body.price_low_day) || 0; // want to get rid of this row.
room.update(req.body) ?
```

Answer (score 0):

In your [model definition](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model) of a column, you can add the option `defaultValue: 0`, but that will only work if you don't provide the key or provide null for the value and not an empty string.  Furthermore, that only applies on creation, not in the update as you appear to be doing.